# Limits of $p/\ln p - q /\ln q$, $p, q$ prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, flows

Is there any $\alpha>0$ for which there are known to exist two sequences of primes, $(p_i), (q_i)$ such that 
$$\alpha = \lim_{i\to\infty} \left(p_i/\ln p_i - q_i /\ln q_i\right)\ ?$$
The motivation here is to ask the simplest possible question about patterns in the primes *after* normalizing to "correct" for the prime number theorem.

More generally, one could do something like this.  First look at the point set $P=\{ p/ \ln p\}$ where $p$ runs over all the primes.  Then view this point set as an atomic measure on ${\Bbb R}$.  Equip some nice set of measures on ${\Bbb R}$ with some appropriately weak topology and construct a dynamical flow bytaking the closure of all the left shifts of $P$.

Is anything non-trivial known about this flow?

Comment: Some examples might be $q_i=2^i-1, p_i=2^i+i$ and $p_i=q_i + 2\lfloor C \log{ q_i} \rfloor$ though proving there are infinitely many such may be quite hard. 100 digits examples of the second kind are easy to find.
If you allow $\alpha$ to be in certain range it might be doable.